# Get the missing column timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a filtered time series dataframe. When I see the missing datetime columns, the figure obtained is as below:

```
df.datetime.diff().plot()
```

[image]

Here, I can manually see the missing datetime values as the spikes. Is there a way to get the start and stop of these datetime column, if for example they are missing for more than one minute?

Example dataframe:

```
dic = {
'datetime' : ['23.3.2021 23:18:00', '23.3.2021 23:19:00', '23.3.2021 23:20:00', '23.3.2021 23:25:00', '23.3.2021 23:26:00', '23.3.2021 23:27:00'],
    'col1':[31.45,38.361,37.0,31.49,32.891, 41],
    'col2':[38.776,38.444,38.945,38.647,39.667,40.0],
    
}
df=pd.DataFrame(dic)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# ensure datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])

# identify values above 1min
m = df['datetime'].diff().gt('1min')

# group the consecutive values above threshold
out = (df.loc[m, 'datetime'].groupby((~m).cumsum())
         .agg(start='min', stop='max')
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

output:

```
                start                stop
0 2021-03-23 23:25:00 2021-03-23 23:25:00
```

Comment: What if I want stop as `23.3.2021 23:26:00` ?